# Need Help Explaining Licensing for Vector Use

Tags: logo, licensing

So, I am trying to make a logo for our school because they are replacing their previous logo. I want to do it using vector graphics. I will be using inkscape. I found that there is a lot of free vectors available that I could use, but am I allowed to use them for our school logo? Can someone explain which kinds I could use, I would how (if I need to) should I give credit to the author of the vector.

Also If it is a simple vector, could I possibly make it myself? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the vector that you're using and the terms of use/copyright for each one. Could you provide which ones you're talking about?

Comment: some artworks are free to use as personal use, some are non commercial but you are not allow to use part of it as a new artwork, some don't allow redistribute it or to share without mentioning the author.

it is most probably that all artworks are free to use under [creative commons licences](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/).